# PDO connections string host

Tags: c#, php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to put my C# input inside my mysql.
I want it that my classmates which im working also can acces the database thats why I dont use localhost. but I keep getting this

error:

> ERROR SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party has not responded correctly after a certain time, or
>   the connected connection failed because the connected host has not
>   responded.

Or isn't this a correct way to put my database online?

php connection string. (I dont know if the host is correct?)

```
$bdd= new PDO ("mysql:host=phpmyadmin.webserver.roc-teraa.nl;port=3306;dbname=wikiparks","$username", "$password");
```

the C#

```
private void btnToevoegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection ParkInfo = new NameValueCollection();
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkNaam", txbPretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkLocatie", txbLocatiePretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkOpeningsDagen", txbOpeningsDagen.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkOpeningsTijden", txbOpeningsTijden.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkPrijzen", txbPrijzenPretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkLeeftijden", txbLeeftijdPretpark.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkTags", txbTags.Text);
                ParkInfo.Add("ParkBeschrijving", rtbBeschrijving.Text);

                byte[] InsertPark = client.UploadValues("http://localhost:8080/WikiParks/index.php", "POST", ParkInfo);
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pretpak succesvol toegevoegd aan de Database");
            }


        }
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: ERROR SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party has not responded correctly after a certain time, or the connected connection failed because the connected host has not responded I've google translated this.

Comment: phpmyadmin.webserver.roc-teraa.nl is 100% incorrect hostname

Comment: Ye, I've already changed it to a few host names. can this be good host? http://panel.webserver.roc-teraa.nl/

Comment: Nope, panel is still missing the real host by a mile. You better read the exact database hostname in the control panel, instead trying at random

Answer (score 0):

```
PDO in dotNET
[enter link description here][1]
  [1]: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SDO_dotNET/

    The SDO_dotNET Class Library is a high level wrapper around the ODBC, OLEDB, SQLServer and SQLite.

Example:
using SqlDB;

/******************************************************************
Sql Server
*******************************************************************/

string server      = @"INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS";
string database = "DEMODB";
string username = "sa";
string password = "";

string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + "; Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password + "";
SDO db_conn = new SDO(connectionString);

Console.WriteLine("isConnected: " + db_conn.isConnected());
if (db_conn == null || !db_conn.isConnected())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connessione non valida.");
    return;
}

string sql = "SELECT ID, Message FROM Logs ORDER BY IDLic;";
DataTable dtLogs = db_conn.SelectTable(sql);

if (dtLogs == null || dtLogs.Rows.Count == 0)
    return;

// Loop with the foreach keyword.
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLogs.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + dr["Message"].ToString().Trim());
}



/******************************************************************
SQLite
*******************************************************************/

string database = @"C:\Users\Utente\mydb.sqlite";

string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + database + "; Version=3; New=True; Compress=True;"; // local
SDO db_conn = new SDO(connectionString);

Console.WriteLine("isConnected: " + db_conn.isConnected());
if (db_conn == null || !db_conn.isConnected())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connessione non valida.");
    return;
}

string sql = "SELECT firstname, surname FROM users ORDER BY firstname;";
DataTable dtLogs = db_conn.SelectTable(sql);

if (dtLogs == null || dtLogs.Rows.Count == 0)
    return;

// Loop with the foreach keyword.
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLogs.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dr["firstname"].ToString().Trim() + " " + dr["surname"].ToString().Trim());
}
```